# Active Directory - Deploying Wallpaper / GPO "Files" Permissions

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, active-directory, desktop-customization

I have tried to deploy wallpaper with active directory and it seems everything is working, up until the point where the image seems to have permission issues.  At first I thought it was the image, but I've tried multiple BMP/JPGs.

Instead of using a shared path, I wanted to push the file to all machines, so in my GPO, to copy the image from the shared folder, I copied it with: Computer Configuration/Preferences/Windows Settings/Files

On the Shared Folder (and originating machines), the permissions look like this:

[image]

But when it gets copied from the Shared Drive, it ends up getting these permissions:

[image]

The wallpaper seems to deploy with a black screen either way, even though if you go into the system customization, the correct image is in the icon.  Using Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 w/Windows 7 Machines.  I'm aware that there is a hotfix, but I'm using Service Pack 1, so I don't think the bug I read about applies.

Comment: Security entries are not copied when you do this.  What folder are you copying it to on the workstations? It looks like it's probably inheriting those permissions from the parent folder it's in.

Comment: C:\Users\Public\Pictures (Just like in the picture).  Okay that makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it wasn't a permissions issue after all.  After updating the image again and doing gpupdate for the 80th time and making it a JPG, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script to run on logon or as a scheduled task to set file permissions.
`icacls C:\Shared\Finance\Metrics /grant:r "Authenticated Users"`